# Student not present against student recorded subject wise

Tags: mysql

I have a student monthly table in mysql
I recorded every days of month 1,2,3,4,5,6..31 in recorded_day column. with subject wise like math,science,English..etc

Month table like:

```
subject          recorded_day
Math              1
science           1
English           1
Math              2
science           2
English           2
Math              4
science           4
English           4
Math              7
science           8
English           9
```

how to write query for retrieving data separated subject wise student not present in class.
i wants retrieve the recorded_day which date student not present in subject wise class

output like

```
subject       recorded_day not present
Math        3,5,6,8,9,10...31
science     3,5,6,7,9......31
English     3,5,6,7,8,10,...31
```

Comment: Is there a calendar table?

Comment: This smells like homework.  Have you tried a query yet?

Comment: Either you record every day, or you don't. Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.Subject, GROUP_CONCAT(t.row order by t.row) 
FROM
(
  SELECT row, subject
  FROM
  (
    SELECT  @row := @row + 1 as row FROM 
    (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all 
     select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 ) t,
    (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all 
     select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 ) t2,
    (SELECT @row:=0) AS t3
  ) as sub, 
  (
    SELECT 'Math' AS subject UNION ALL SELECT 'science'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'English') AS subjects
  WHERE row <= 31 
) AS t
LEFT JOIN Table1 AS t1 
         ON t.row = t1.recorded_day AND t.subject = t1.subject
WHERE t1.recorded_day IS NULL
  GROUP BY t.subject;
```

Here's how it works:

1. Generate a sequence number from 1 to 31.
2. Get the cartesian product for this list for each subject.
3. `LEFT JOIN` the original table to get those days that are not present.
4. Use `GROUP_CONCAT` with `GROUP BY`.

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8f5a1/22)

Results:

```
| Subject |                                          NotPresent 
|---------|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| English | 3,5,6,7,8,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31 |
|    Math | 3,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31 |
| science | 3,5,6,7,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31 |
```

Comment: @SSatya Incidentally, don't get too hung up on the values in those SELECTs. It's just a hack for generating rows. Something like this would have the same effect... `SELECT @i:=@i+1 i
  FROM 
     ( SELECT 'a' UNION SELECT 'b' UNION SELECT 'c' ) a
   , ( SELECT 'g' UNION SELECT 'm' UNION SELECT 'o' ) b
   , ( SELECT 'r' UNION SELECT 'b' UNION SELECT 'c' UNION SELECT 'd' ) c
   , ( SELECT @i:=0 ) x;
`

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a table (month_days) with days of months and all subjects:

```
days                 subject 
1                     Math
2                     Math 
3                     Math 
.
.
.
31(or 30, 28, 29)     English
1                     English
2                     English 
3                     English 
.
.
.
31(or 30, 28, 29)     English
.
.

SELECT subject, GROUP_CONCAT(recorded_day SEPARATOR ',') 
FROM month_days m_d
LEFT JOIN table t on t.recorded_day=m_d.days and t.subject=m_d.subject
WHERE t.recorded_day is null
GROUP BY subject;
```

Comment: This does not attempt to answer the question - which is fair enough, because the question doesn't even attempt to ask one.

Comment: i have already try only presented day i was retrived i wants absent day    select
      pl.subject,
  GROUP_CONCAT(pl.recorded_day ORDER BY
        pl.recorded_day)
    dateonly
    from
        Student_table_2017_10 pl
    where
        pl.strudent_id='1234' 
        and pl.class='X' 
        and pl.studentname='ram'        
        group by
        pl.subject